# Mongo conditional find

Tags: mongodb

So I have this article page and I need to place related articles below the current article body.
There are certain attributes that I use to find similar articles but in case there isn't any, or if there is less than 2 found, I need to add just some other articles to the result.
So if a given article has a tag "Development", I need to search for 2 other articles with that tag, and if there is less than 2 that have this tag, I need to pull just some other articles.
Right now the flow is:

1. I make a request to get an article using query
2. I make request for related articles using the result of the first request.
   But now I have difficulty understand how to make another request or put a condition into the second request to optimally get another article(s).

I appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

```
const article =await "your collection". find({tag:"Development"}).limit(2);
const x=2 - article.length
while(x>0){
var y=await "your collection". findOne();
article.push(y);
x--;
}
```